# What is wrong with the below lambda expression for multiplication(C#3.0)

Tags: c#-3.0

```
List<double> y = new List<double> {   0.4807, -3.7070, -4.5582, 
                                    -11.2126, -0.7733,  3.7269, 
                                      2.7672,  8.3333,  4.7023 };

List<double> d1 = y.ForEach(i => i * 2);
```

**Error: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement**

What is wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`List<T>.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx) doesn't perform a conversion: it executes the given delegate for each item, but that's all. That's why it has a `void` return type - and why the parameter type is `Action<T>` rather than something like `Func<T, TResult>`. This last part is why you've got a compilation error. You're basically trying to do:

```
Action<double> = i => i * 2;
```

That will give you the same compilation error.

If you want to stick within the `List<T>` methods (e.g. because you're using .NET 2.0) you can use [`List<T>.ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf(v=VS.100).aspx):

```
List<double> d1 = y.ConvertAll(i => i * 2);
```

Answer (score 6):

Try instead:

```
List<double> d1 = y.Select(i => i * 2).ToList();
```

Comment: `ForEach` takes `Action<T>` — a function which returns nothing.

Comment: You're just discarding the results of the multiplication. There's nothing in your code to put them into a list as the result.

Comment: a foreach is a loop which returns nothing

Answer (score 1):

`List.Foreach` takes an `Action<>` delegate which does not return anything, so you cannot use it to create a new list that way. As others have pointed out, using ForEach is not the best option here. A sample on how to perform the operation using `ForEach` might help to understand why:

```
List<double> y = new List<double> {   0.4807, -3.7070, -4.5582, 
                                    -11.2126, -0.7733,  3.7269, 
                                      2.7672,  8.3333,  4.7023 };

List<double> d1 = new List<double>();

Action<double> a = i => d1.Add(i*2);
y.ForEach(a);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
List<double> d1 = y.ForEach(i => i = i * 2);
```

Comment: This will have absolutely no effect on the list. `i` is equivalent to a function parameter; modifying `i` is just modifying a local, not the value contained within the list.

Comment: Sorry. It did not y.ForEach(i => i = i * 2);